# Using PHP backend with React Application

Tags: php, reactjs, amazon-s3

I have a react app and I run npm run build to generate a build package that I upload to S3. let's say www.test.com/build/

but I have a PHP backend that should be responsible for serving the index.html (from www.test.com/index.html)

since there's no connection with the S3 bucket and the PHP app I don't know how to deal with the hashed names in the react app

I can't generate the build package without the hashes because I will lose the cache buster.

what are some good practices to work with react apps and backend apps. In this case is PHP but I think the problem should be the same with a NodeJS backend hosted in a different server.

I'm using AWS CodePipeline to build the react app (npm run build) and the php app (composer install)

Comment: All s3 can do is serve static files.  Are you running php somewhere?  You can't run php scripts from s3 with no php server.

Comment: correct. S3 only has the /build directory and the PHP server needs somehow to include those .JS files but since the filenames are hashed I can't just include them.

Comment: PHP doesn't need to include your .JS files. you should point your domain to the s3 bucket instead of your php server, then create a subdomain e.g. `api.test.com` to access your PHP API. Access the API via `fetch` or other ajax methods

Comment: however if you still want PHP as the entry point, you need to look at server side rendering. Here's a blog post which might help you https://sebastiandedeyne.com/server-side-rendering-javascript-from-php/

Comment: @kkesley I´m not looking for server side rendering. basically I need to host all the access in S3 and in the PHP application (elastic beranstalk) just render the index.html as an entry point. the easy way is to deploy to s3. copy the /public/index.html and paste it in the PHP server as index.php but I wanted a more automated way of doing this. thank you!

Comment: why would you want to have the entry point in the beanstalk? Can't you just use s3 website?

Comment: @kkesley because the PHP is checking if the request is a network request. detecting the language, etc, etc and then returns the index.html. I will probably going to make a CURL to s3. get the html content and render it with PHP. was looking for a more efficient way of doing that. thanks

Comment: can you consider lambda @ edge instead of php in elasticbeanstalk? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP doesn't need to know about JS files with or without hashes. Your PHP server will be serving index.html file only. Your index.html file contains entry point javascript files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

When your PHP server serves index.html file, on client's browser it will load necessary react and other js code via chunk using vendor and index files(or whatever your file names are).

**What if you need to use vendor.bundle.js and index.js with hashes?**

Following modules will help you.

Module-1: https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-manifest-plugin
this module will help you to keep track of hashed files generated.

Module-2: https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-replace-webpack-plugin
Using this module you can replace you entry point files with hashes file names you get from module-1.

Answer (score -1):

1.You might know this but just confirming if you want to do this without hosting the index file on the  (elastic beranstalk) server why don't you use `<iframe>` tag on to the index file.

2.You can use `$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');` method of php that is use less code and efforts then curl.

3. `curl` which you already know.